# A problem on function of a function

Tags: functions

I am stuck with this problem,

> A function $f(x)$ is defined as $f(x)
>  = \sinh(x)$. Another function $g(x)$ is such that $f(g(x)) = x$.
>
> Find the value of $\large
>  g(\frac{e^{2012}-1}{2e^{1006}})$

I tried representing $f(x) =\large \frac{e^{2x}-1}{2e^{x}}$,and then using some algebraic manipulation but I am unable to get the correct answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(g(x))=x$, then $f$ and $g$ are inverses.  Thus $g(f(x))=x$ as well.  The answer is then $g(f(1006))=1006$.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to notice $\mathrm{sinh}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection. Hence, any right inverse is a left inverse. It follows

$$g(\frac{e^{2012}-1}{2e^{1006}}) = g\circ f(1006) = 1006$$

Comment: Do you mean $1006$?